# Why do I need a double ampersand when getting values from a HashMap?

Tags: rust

I'm having some trouble with references in rust. I have the following code that does not compile:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();

    map.insert(&0, &0);
    map.insert(&1, &1);

    assert_eq!(map.get(&0), Some(&0));
}
```

The compilation error I get is:

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> rust_doubt.rs:9:5
  |
9 |     assert_eq!(map.get(&0), Some(&0));
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected &{integer}, found integral variable
  |
  = note: expected type `std::option::Option<&&{integer}>`
             found type `std::option::Option<&{integer}>`
  = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Sure enough, if I change the line:

`assert_eq!(map.get(&0), Some(&0));` to `assert_eq!(map.get(&0), Some(&&0));` (double ampersand) the code compiles

#### Questions:

1. `map.insert(&0, &0)` inserts pointers to two integer literals into the map. I'm not sure how this is even possible since I have not used a variable anywhere. How can I have a reference to a literal? I was expecting the compiler to make me do this:

```rust
let a = 0;
let b = 0
map.insert(&a, &b);
```

In other words, what does `&0` even mean? Does it allocate memory for the literal and return a reference to it? If so, then am I correct in assuming that no two `&0`s would point to the same memory?

2. Why do I have to do `Some(&&0)` instead of just `Some(&0)`? What does `&&0` even mean? I understand that `**ptr` means dereferencing a variable twice to get the underlying value. But I can't quite imagine the reverse - how can you "refer" an integer literal twice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the signature of `insert` and `get` you will realize that they handle things differently.

Starting from a `HashMap<K, V>`:

- `fn insert(&mut self, k: K, v: V) -> Option<V>`.
- `fn get(&self, k: &K) -> Option<&V>` (simplified).

As you can see, `insert` takes **ownership**, handling **values**, while `get` takes and returns a **reference**.

Therefore, if you `insert` `&1`, you `get` `Some(&&1)` back: one more layer of reference.

---

The question, then, is why is there no error from `.get(&0)`: isn't it lacking a level of reference?

Well, I cheated and simplified the signature of get, [the exact signature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) is:

```
pub fn get<Q: ?Sized>(&self, k: &Q) -> Option<&V> where
    K: Borrow<Q>,
    Q: Hash + Eq,
```

And it turns out that `&T` implements `Borrow<T>`, so you can call get with `&K` for `&&K`.

---

If you manage to get the compiler to give you the type of the `HashMap`, it's a bit easier:

```
assert_eq!(map, ());
```

Results in:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:9:5
  |
9 |     assert_eq!(map, ());
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::collections::HashMap`, found ()
  |
  = note: expected type `std::collections::HashMap<&{integer}, &{integer}>`
             found type `()`
  = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Which shows you what type the compiler figured out for `K` and `V`, and indeed it will be `&{integer}`, since you pass `&0` to `insert` which takes key and value by value.

---

As for the issue of lifetimes:

1. Not all checks are done in a single pass. In particular, borrowing/lifetime checks are generally done *after* type checking.
2. Literals have the `'static` lifetime, just  like `"Hello"` has the `&'static str` type.

The compiler automatically reserves memory somewhere in the program for literals, and will "borrow" them as necessary. This means that creating a reference to a literal integer is perfectly fine: `&0i32` has type `&'static i32`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However, what does `&&0` _mean_ ? For eg, `&0` points to the address in memory of an integer literal (I think). Which means that no 2 literals should have the same address. However, `assert_eq!(&0, &0);` works. But why? Due to auto-dereferencing assert_eq ends up comparing the values instead of the address?

Comment: @KevinMartinJose: The compiler is allowed, at its discretion, to merge equivalent literals together. Therefore, whether the address of `0` matches the address of `0` is not something you can rely on. Actually, you could even have the address of `"Hello"` matching the address of `"Hello, World"` as one is the prefix of the other. As for `&&0`, formally it's a reference to a reference which would be implemented as a pointer to a local variable containing the pointer to the literal 0.

Comment: @KevinMartinJose: `assert_eq!(&0, &0)` is different, though. Look at the documentation for `Eq` and `PartialEq`, and you'll notice an implementation of `impl Eq for &A where A: Eq`, which peels away the layers of references as long as there is the same number on each side. To compare raw pointers, you need to ask for raw pointers: `assert_eq!(&0 as *const _, &0 as *const _);`