# How to use a vector of string slices

Tags: rust

I am wondering why this works

```
fn main() {
    let v: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();
    let s: &str = v.get(0).unwrap();
    let new_string = String::from(s);
    println!("{}", new_string);
}
```

but not this one:

```
fn main() {
    let v: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();
    let s = v.get(0).unwrap();
    let new_string = String::from(s);
    println!("{}", new_string);
}
```

I get the following error from the second snippet:

```
let new_string = String::from(s);
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<&&str>` is not implemented for `std::string::String`
```

Comment: Not exact duplicates but see [Rust HashMap: Why do I need a double ampersand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54982977/rust-hashmap-why-do-i-need-a-double-ampersand) and [why is “&&” being used here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828013/why-is-being-used-here)

Comment: Not familiar with rust. If it has a `type()` function or something similar I would print that out for `s` in both the snippets above and compare. I suspect it has to do with the double reference (`&&str`) shown in the error.

Comment: TL;DR: you have a vector of references (`T == &str`), `get` returns an optional reference (`Option<&T>`), which means you got two references (`Option<&&str>`).

Comment: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a1640110af6b89d85daa5ad655f97663

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Vec::<T>::get()` method returns an `Option<&T>`, that is, an option of a reference into the vector. Because your vector already contains references (`&str`), it means that `get()` in your case returns `Option<&&str>`.

Now, the reason why your first example compiles is that by being explicit about the type of the `s` variable you cause [deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods) to fire, that is, the compiler will automatically insert a dereference operator:

```rust
// You write this:
let s: &str = v.get(0).unwrap();

// Compiler actually does this:
let s: &str = *v.get(0).unwrap();
```

Then, because there [exists](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-From%3C%26%27_%20str%3E) an implementation of the `From<&str>` trait for `String`, the compiler accepts the `String::from(s)` call.

In the second piece, however, without an explicit type annotation the type assigned to `s` is `&&str`:

```rust
let s: &&str = v.get(0).unwrap();
```

This changes the situation with the `String::from()` method: there is no `From<&&str>` implementation for `String`, and the compiler fails to compile the code.

A logical question here would be why no deref coercion happens in this case, when `s` is used as an argument for `from()`? The answer is that deref coercion does not happen for generic methods, and `String::from` is a generic method because it relies on the type parameter of the `From` trait. The compiler can't do a deref coercion, because it is [totally possible](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4061a2d804bc160797bc75f17bef8247) (in principle) to have both `From<&str>` and `From<&&str>` methods which would potentially do different things.

Even if `From<&&str>` does not exist now, and the compiler would have applied a deref coercion, it would make the code brittle against future evolution: if for some reason `From<&&str>` is added in a future version of the standard library, your code may silently break, because it will now call a different method than before, with potentially different logic.

(Naturally, I'm not saying that `From<&&str>` would indeed be added in the future libstd version; this is generic reasoning applicable to any kind of trait, in any code base).